# Service-Worker not caching files with Vite + VitePWA

Tags: vue.js, progressive-web-apps, service-worker, vite, workbox

I got a service-worker.js that works fine with Webpack but now after migrating to Vite, the same service-worker.js is registered but not caching files and offline mode is not working (without any errors).

How can I debug this? what could be the problem?

Versions I'm using:

```
"workbox-cacheable-response": "7.0.0",
"workbox-cli": "7.0.0",
"workbox-expiration": "7.0.0",
"workbox-routing": "7.0.0",
"workbox-strategies": "7.0.0"
"vite": "^4.4.2"
"vite-plugin-pwa": "^0.16.4"
"vue": "^3.3.4"
```

service-worker.js:

```
import { registerRoute, NavigationRoute } from 'workbox-routing';
import {
    NetworkFirst,
    StaleWhileRevalidate,
    CacheFirst,
} from 'workbox-strategies';

// Used for filtering matches based on status code, header, or both
import { CacheableResponsePlugin } from 'workbox-cacheable-response';
// Used to limit entries in cache, remove entries after a certain period of time
import { ExpirationPlugin } from 'workbox-expiration';

import * as navigationPreload from 'workbox-navigation-preload';
import { NetworkOnly } from 'workbox-strategies';

// Disable console logs
self.__WB_DISABLE_DEV_LOGS = true

// console.log(self.__WB_MANIFEST)

// Cache Google Fonts with a stale-while-revalidate strategy, with
// a maximum number of entries.
registerRoute(
    ({ url }) => url.origin === 'https://fonts.googleapis.com' ||
        url.origin === 'https://fonts.gstatic.com',
    new StaleWhileRevalidate({
        cacheName: 'google-fonts',
        plugins: [
            new ExpirationPlugin({ maxEntries: 20 }),
        ],
    }),
);


// Cache CSS, JS, and Web Worker requests with a Stale While Revalidate strategy
registerRoute(
    // Check to see if the request's destination is style for stylesheets, script for JavaScript, or worker for web worker
    ({ request }) =>
        request.destination === 'style' ||
        request.destination === 'script' ||
        request.destination === 'worker',
    // Use a Stale While Revalidate caching strategy
    new StaleWhileRevalidate({
        // Put all cached files in a cache named 'assets'
        cacheName: 'assets',
        plugins: [
            // Ensure that only requests that result in a 200 status are cached
            new CacheableResponsePlugin({
                statuses: [200],
            }),
        ],
    }),
);

// Cache images with a Cache First strategy
registerRoute(
    // Check to see if the request's destination is style for an image
    ({ request }) => request.destination === 'image',
    // Use a Cache First caching strategy
    new CacheFirst({
        // Put all cached files in a cache named 'images'
        cacheName: 'images',
        plugins: [
            // Ensure that only requests that result in a 200 status are cached
            new CacheableResponsePlugin({
                statuses: [200],
            }),
            // Don't cache more than 50 items, and expire them after 30 days
            new ExpirationPlugin({
                maxEntries: 50,
                maxAgeSeconds: 60 * 60 * 24 * 30, // 30 Days
            }),
        ],
    }),
);


/**
 * Offline page
 */
const CACHE_NAME = 'offline-html';
// This assumes /offline.html is a URL for your self-contained
// (no external images or styles) offline page.
const FALLBACK_HTML_URL = '/offline';
// Populate the cache with the offline HTML page when the
// service worker is installed.
self.addEventListener('install', async (event) => {
    event.waitUntil(
        caches.open(CACHE_NAME)
            .then((cache) => cache.add(FALLBACK_HTML_URL))
    );
});

navigationPreload.enable();

const networkOnly = new NetworkOnly();
const navigationHandler = async (params) => {
    try {
        // Attempt a network request.
        return await networkOnly.handle(params);
    } catch (error) {
        // If it fails, return the cached HTML.
        return caches.match(FALLBACK_HTML_URL, {
            cacheName: CACHE_NAME,
        });
    }
};

// Register this strategy to handle all navigations.
registerRoute(
    new NavigationRoute(navigationHandler)
);
```

vite.config.js (only the important part):

```
    ...
    return defineConfig({
        plugins: [
            ...
            VitePWA({ 
                registerType: 'autoUpdate',
                injectRegister: null,
                // swSrc: 'resources/pwa/service-worker.js',
                includeAssets: [
                    'favicon.ico',
                    'assets/icons/*.png',
                ],
                manifest: {
                    name: app_name,
                    short_name: app_name,
                    theme_color: app_theme_color,
                    background_color: app_bg_color,
                    display: "standalone",
                    scope: "/",
                    start_url: "/",
                    orientation: "portrait",
                    splash_pages: null,
                    icons: [{
                        "src": "/assets/icons/icon-48x48.png",
                        "sizes": "48x48",
                        "type": "image/png",
                        // "purpose": "any maskable"
                    },
                    {
                        "src": "/assets/icons/icon-72x72.png",
                        "sizes": "72x72",
                        "type": "image/png",
                        // "purpose": "any maskable"
                    },
                    {
                        "src": "/assets/icons/icon-96x96.png",
                        "sizes": "96x96",
                        "type": "image/png",
                        // "purpose": "any maskable"
                    },
                    {
                        "src": "/assets/icons/icon-144x144.png",
                        "sizes": "144x144",
                        "type": "image/png",
                        // "purpose": "any maskable"
                    },
                    {
                        "src": "/assets/icons/icon-168x168.png",
                        "sizes": "168x168",
                        "type": "image/png",
                        // "purpose": "any maskable"
                    },
                    {
                        "src": "/assets/icons/icon-192x192.png",
                        "sizes": "192x192",
                        "type": "image/png",
                        // "purpose": "any maskable"
                    },
                    {
                        "src": "/assets/icons/icon-256x256.png",
                        "sizes": "256x256",
                        "type": "image/png",
                        // "purpose": "any mabskable"
                    },
                    {
                        "src": "/assets/icons/icon-512x512.png",
                        "sizes": "512x512",
                        "type": "image/png",
                        // "purpose": "any maskable"
                    }]
                },
                strategies: 'injectManifest',
                injectManifest: {
                    injectionPoint: undefined
                },
                srcDir: 'resources/pwa',
                filename: 'service-worker.js',
                workbox: {
                    globPatterns: ['**/*.{js,css,html,ico,png,svg,webp}'],
                    // Don't fallback on document based (e.g. `/some-page`) requests
                    // Even though this says `null` by default, I had to set this specifically to `null` to make it work
                    navigateFallback: null,
                },
                devOptions: {
                    enabled: true
                }
            }),
...
```

- I checked the Cache Storage and the only thing that cached was the '/offline' (but not really redirecting when offline).
- I asked chatGPT and tried some basic suggestions.
- I also tried number of stuff like adding this block to workbox object:

```
runtimeCaching: [{
    urlPattern: ({ url }) => {
        return url.pathname.startsWith('/')
    },
    handler: 'CacheFirst',
    options: {
        cacheName: 'build-cache',
        cacheableResponse: {
            statuses: [0, 200]
        }
    }
}]
```

Any help or advice would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue? I have the very same problem, I just used their basic examples but there is absolutely no cache.

Comment: @RobinSchambach No, unfortunately I haven't found a solution with this method. I'm using prebuild service worker for now until I'll find a good solution.